# Pointrange plot with boxplot type grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I have data that could be plotted with a box plot, but n for each box is only 3. I would like to plot them using a pointrange type of plot in ggplot2. By default, they come on top of each other. How can I group my points side by side as they get grouped in boxplot?

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- rnorm(12, 3,5) # Real data are not always normally distributed.
y <- c(rep("T1", 6), rep("T2", 6))
z <- rep(c(10,20),6)

dat <- data.frame(Treatment = y, Temp = z, Meas = x)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(Treatment, Meas))
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Temp)))
```

**Edit:** I updated the question to exclude bootstrapping as advised (original idea was to use confidence intervals as error bars. Too many questions for one question =D). More detailed bootstrapping question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351704/monte-carlo-nonparametric-confidence-intervals-for-mean-estimate)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two questions (try to avoid that).

1. Bootstrapping. How do you bootstrap from a sample of 3 points, where you don't know the underlying distribution?
2. Line ranges. I've used your original data to construct line ranges. For a line range, you just need a min, max and middle value:

   ```
   ##First rearrange your data frame
   dat = with(dat, dat[order(Treatment, Temp, Meas),])
   dat$type = c("min", "mid", "max")

   library(reshape2)
   dat1 = dcast(dat, Treatment + Temp ~  type, value.var = "Meas")
   ```

Then plot as usual:

```
    p = ggplot(dat1) +
        geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max, 
                            y=mid,x=Treatment, group=Temp),
           position=position_dodge(width=0.20))
```

The position arguments stops the lines being placed on top of each other. This gives:

[image: Example line range plot]

Comment: Ah, position_dodge is the command. Thanks! I think I figured out the bootstrapping `(function(a,b) mean(a[b])` instead of just using "a". `boot.ci()` from "boot" package gives me 5 different types of bootstrapping intervals. Is "basic" the right one for this case?

Comment: Sorry never used that package.

Comment: I have to second the warning/concern about bootstrapping with three points ... !

Comment: Mhh...you're right. It's not possible without doing assumptions. Assuming normal distribution for bootstrapping would have the "same" effect than using sd or se, right? i.e. that intervals are drawn from a normal distribution, although the distribution is not that normal (two points very close and one pretty far from them for example). Of course one can get almost whatever result when drawing 3 random points from a normal distribution with a large CV. Maybe I should make a question about this to CrossValidated.

Comment: @Largh Why use CV at all. Just display the three points using a scatter plot.

Comment: Because I would like to show in the figure whether the groups are significantly different (in addition to permutation 2-way ANOVA). The 3 points are averages measured from one experimental unit. I would use them as replicates. There is a different number of measurements within each group.